# What causes Installshield to fail (error: 1628)?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2019, odbc, windows-installer

I'm trying to setup a DB/C FS 4.0 ODBC driver on our server to connect to a client's database, and am receiving an error from the Installshield executable: "1628: Failed to complete installation."

The driver installed with no issues on my personal workstation running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. The server I am trying to install on is running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

I tried logging the installation and was able to get some output from the Windows installer side:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 6/23/2020  16:07:39  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\Driver\8\Intel 32\IDriver.exe ===
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:773]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:800]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:803]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:817]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:833]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:833]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:845]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:846]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:846]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:852]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:857]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:861]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{3DCF5693-5388-45C9-A9A4-F03B5C516CAD}'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:863]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:39:912]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:027]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 1
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:034]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:036]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:036]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:036]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:042]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{3DCF5693-5388-45C9-A9A4-F03B5C516CAD}'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:042]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:042]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:042]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Control 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:042]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'c:\SetupMSI.log'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: No Command Line.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           '(none)'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{3DCF5693-5388-45C9-A9A4-F03B5C516CAD}'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{3DCF5693-5388-45C9-A9A4-F03B5C516CAD}'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:044]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:046]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:046]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:047]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:047]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:047]: Package name extracted from package path: 'DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:048]: Package to be registered: 'DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi'
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:051]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:052]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:052]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:052]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:052]: Running product '{3DCF5693-5388-45C9-A9A4-F03B5C516CAD}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:054]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiSystemRebootPending property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:054]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:054]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:058]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:059]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\Favorites
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:060]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:062]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\Documents
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:062]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:062]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:062]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:063]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:064]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:065]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Local
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:065]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\Pictures
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:066]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:066]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:066]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:066]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:069]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\Desktop
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:069]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:069]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:069]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:070]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:070]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:070]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:072]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:076]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'EC2'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'Amazon.com'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\{F9AA98F9-291D-42DB-86A7-F3B277529911}\DBC FS 4.0 (ODBC Driver).msi'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:078]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:078]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:078]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI in quiet mode
=== Logging started: 6/23/2020  16:07:40 ===
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:080]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:081]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:081]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:081]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:081]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Font 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:081]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:082]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:357]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:464]: MsiOpenPackageEx is returning 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:464]: MsiOpenPackage is returning 0
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:470]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SETUPEXEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Administrator.XXXX\Downloads\Send-Archive\Dbcfs4_ODBC_Setup'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:491]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISSETUPDRIVEN property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:491]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ALLUSERS property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:528]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790541 for thread 15040
MSI (c) (E0:C0) [16:07:40:530]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790537 for thread 15040
=== Verbose logging stopped: 6/23/2020  16:07:40 ===
```

but wasn't able to discern anything useful from it.

What could be the cause of this error?

How can I solve/work around it?

Comment: This looks like an Installscript MSI launched without the associated setup.exe wrapper by means of setting the [ISSETUPDRIVEN property to 1](https://www.itninja.com/question/issetupdriven-2). Do you have the option of running the installation via the original setup.exe to try that out?

Answer (score 0):

What I observed is there are no "MSI (s)" lines, only "MSI (c)" lines are there.
So, your installer didn't go to elevated mode.
Launch your setup or exe with "Run as admin" option and try.

Also, share the log file as in below line.
MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'c:\SetupMSI.log'.

Comment: Definitely ran as admin, and what is pasted in my OP is the contents of SetupMSI.log